# Combine two column into a column in dictionary format after performing groupby operation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

## I have a data frame as shown below
df:

```
cust_id      products              rec_product          conf      sup
1            ['phone', 'tv']       ball                 0.68      0.12
1            ['phone', 'tv']       bat                  0.21      0.34
1            ['phone', 'tv']       book                 0.02      0.25
2            ['bat']               ball                 0.97      0.18 
2            ['bat']               book                 0.65      0.65
2            ['bat']               phone                0.23      0.36
2            ['bat']               tv                   0.03      0.48
```

Where I wants to combine `rec_product` and `conf` column as dictionary after performing `groupby`

## Expected output:

```
cust_id      products             prod_conf                                            prod_sup    
1            ['phone', 'tv']      {'ball':0.68, 'bat':0.21, 'book':0.02}               {'ball':0.12, 'bat':0.34, 'book':0.25}
2            ['bat']              {'ball':0.97, 'book':0.65, 'phone':0.23, 'tv':0.03}  {'ball':0.18, 'book':0.65, 'phone':0.36, 'tv':0.48}
```

I tried below code it worked. But I would like to know is there any faster methods than this, which consume less memory and executes faster.

Combine `rec_product` and `conf` into one column

```
prod_conf_df = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'conf'], ascending=[True, 
                                        False]).set_index('rec_product').groupby(['cust_id', 'products']).\
                                       apply(lambda x: x['conf'].to_dict()).reset_index(name='prod_conf')
```

Combine `rec_product` and `sup` into one column

```
prod_sup_df = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'conf'], ascending=[True, 
                                        False]).set_index('rec_product').groupby(['cust_id']).\
                                       apply(lambda x: x['sup'].to_dict()).reset_index(name='prod_sup')
```

combine both the above dfs into one

```
combined_df = pd.merge(prod_conf_df, prod_supp_df, on='cust_id', how='inner')
```

Comment: have you tried something like:
`df['prod_conf'] = df[['rec_product', 'conf']].to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `groupby`'s + `apply`'s..I would suggest doing all the aggregations using a single `groupby` inside a comprehension

```
def dictify(k, g):
    return {
        'cust_id': k,
        'products' : g['products'].iat[0],
        'prod_conf': dict(zip(g['rec_product'], g['conf'])),
        'prod_sup' : dict(zip(g['rec_product'], g['sup']))
    }    

s = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'conf'], ascending=[True, False])
s = pd.DataFrame(dictify(k, g) for k, g in s.groupby('cust_id', sort=False))
```

##### Result

```
   cust_id         products                                                prod_conf                                                 prod_sup
0        1  ['phone', 'tv']                {'ball': 0.68, 'bat': 0.21, 'book': 0.02}                {'ball': 0.12, 'bat': 0.34, 'book': 0.25}
1        2          ['bat']  {'ball': 0.97, 'book': 0.65, 'phone': 0.23, 'tv': 0.03}  {'ball': 0.18, 'book': 0.65, 'phone': 0.36, 'tv': 0.48}
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer. Whether it is  s = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'conf'], ascending=[True, False]) or df = df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'conf'], ascending=[True, False])

Comment: Glad to help @Danish! Please check the edit. if you dont want to overwrite the original dataframe then use a new variable to store the result.